# Disable formatting for sections of code

Tags: visual-studio-2008, formatting

Using Visual Studio 2008 (without Resharper), is it possible to disable formatting for a section of code?

E.g. I like to define flag-type enums with 1 << n notation, as I feel this makes them more readable, however the auto-formatting of Visual Studio removes the tab-spacings that align the enum values:

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
   Value1        = 1,
   Value2        = 1 << 1,
   AnotherValue3 = 1 << 2, 
   AFinalValue4  = 1 << 3
}
```

becomes:

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 1 << 1,
    AnotherValue3 = 1 << 2, 
    AFinalValue4 = 1 << 3
}
```

i.e. I'm looking to, for example, surround the section in a #noformat region or something similar..

Comment: This is great question, I'm looking exactly for the same, have you found anything yet since that 7 years ago? :)

Comment: I'm afraid not, no